# SSL protect a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have ssl installed on the server but i want to use it only for a particular directory for eaxmple  for www.domain.com/users and not for any other thing on the server eg. www.domain.com?

Comment: Your going to need more details, operating system? Web service?

Comment: i am using apache2 with ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want two things.

1. Require SSL on that directory:

   ```
   <Directory "/usr/local/www/path/to/directory">
       SSLRequireSSL
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Redirect people reaching that page by http to use https:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/directory [NC]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing; if this doesn't work well for your situation, say so and we can work out the details of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you really want to do what you're asking (use SSL for one directory and *deny* it for others) -- More common is wanting to *require* SSL for one directory and allowing it to be optional for all others.

To require SSL simply create a `<Directory>` (or `<Location>`) block and add the `SSLRequireSSL` directive to it ([More info on that directive can be found in the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl)).

If you indeed **do** want to deny SSL for all other directories you can use mod_rewrite on top of the above solution to do so (rewrite `https://anything-that-doesnt-match/your/secure/directory` to `http://....`), but note that some browsers may balk at https:// URLs being rewritten to http://.
Implementing that mod_rewrite rule is between you, [the mod_rewrite section of the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and whatever alcoholic beverage you use to cope with mod_rewrite :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i am trying to  protect the user area with ssl while the other areas are just http.

Comment: @Aditya Normally you would *require* SSL for the user area (with SSLRequireSSL), and allow it to be optional for the other parts of the site (which is the default behavior).  This requires a lot less configuration-wrangling than prohibiting it for the rest of the site :)